# Проблема с меню (Z-index)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток, делаю портфолио для FCC, параллельно изучая front-end сферу, столкнулся с такой проблемой, при написании меню z-index не работает должным образом

Как это выглядит сейчас:

[JSFiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/jdmr8vm1/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.activatemenu').click(function() {
    $('.topmenu').animate({
      height: "100%"
    }, 800);
    $('.activatemenu').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("display", "inline");
    $('.deactivatemenu').fadeIn(500);
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "500");
    $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "500");
    $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "1");
  });
  $('.deactivatemenu').click(function() {
    $('.topmenu').animate({
      height: "3rem"
    }, 800);
    $('.activatemenu').fadeIn(500);
    $('.deactivatemenu').fadeOut(1000);
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");
    $("html,body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "500");
    $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "500");
    $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "auto");
  });
});
```

```css
h1.main {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #eee;
  line-height: 0.5;
  margin-top: 40%;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  left: 10%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.mobiletext {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.deactivatemenu {
  display: none;
}

.topmenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="activatemenu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <p class="mobiletext">Menu</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="deactivatemenu">
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
    <p class="mobiletext">Close</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5 col-md-offset-4">
  <h1 class="main">Тут какой-то контент</h1>
</div>
```

Второй вариант:

[JSFiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/jdmr8vm1/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.activatemenu').click(function() {
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("position", "absolute");
    $('.topmenu').animate({
      height: "100%"
    }, 800);
    $('.activatemenu').fadeOut(250);
    $('.deactivatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "0");
  });
  $('.deactivatemenu').click(function() {
    $('.topmenu').animate({
      height: "3rem"
    }, 800);
    $('.activatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.deactivatemenu').fadeOut(250);
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");
    $("html,body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "0");
  });
});
```

```css
h1.main {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #eee;
  line-height: 0.5;
  margin-top: 40%;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  left: 10%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.mobiletext {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.deactivatemenu {
  display: none;
}

.topmenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="activatemenu">
    <p class="mobiletext">Menu</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="deactivatemenu">
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
    <p class="mobiletext">Close</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5 col-md-offset-4">
  <h1 class="main">Тут какой-то контент</h1>
</div>
```

Мне нужно меню перекрывало весь контент сайта за исключением кнопки close

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {      
     $('.activatemenu').click(function(){
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("position", "absolute");       
        $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "100%"}, 800);
        $('.activatemenu').fadeOut(250);
        $('.deactivatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
        $("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "0");
     }); 
     $('.deactivatemenu').click(function(){
        $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "3rem"}, 800);
        $('.activatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.deactivatemenu').fadeOut(250);
        $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
        $("html,body").css("overflow-x","hidden");
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "0");
     }); 
  });

</script>
```

Comment: а что не так со вторым вариантом? _Как это должно выглядеть_ - это разве не решение твоего вопроса?

Comment: @Grundy кнопочку close видите? И я не вижу. В скобочках я поместил что с этим вариантом не так.

Comment: В JSFiddle #2 - вижу

Comment: _В скобочках я поместил что с этим вариантом не так_ - на данный момент непонятно что ты хочешь: у тебя есть два варианта, один рабочий другой нерабочий? И ты хочешь чтобы нерабочий стал рабочим? ну так просто посмотри чем они отличаются

Comment: @Grundy Ещё раз объясняю, второй вариант мне не подходит так как там контент сайта не скрывается, а второй не подходит из-за того что z-index скрывает кнопки menu | close

Comment: Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы скрывалось всё, кроме кнопки close когда меню открывается

Comment: Стоит перенести это в сам вопрос. Сейчас в нем ничего этого нет. Плюс, возможно, стоит добавить картинки, с тем как это сейчас и как должно быть. Ну и стоит перенести код с jsfiddle в сам вопрос.

Comment: а почему просто кнопку close Не поместить внутрь topmenu?

Comment: Очень нехороший паттерн. Совет: перенесите стили все в css. В jquery для схлопывания меню и других элементов есть методы .show(200) .hide(200) .toggleClass('active') .slideToggle(200). Суть в том, что логику и открытого и закрытого состояния можно вынести в css, а переключение классов сделать на js. Если заинтересует, я мог бы набросать код.

Comment: @larrymacbarry я очень слаб в js, был бы очень благодарен, я пробовал через .hide, но почему-то меню меню открывалось и закрывалось по нескольку раз за один клик

Comment: @Grundy С этой стороны я как то и не посмотрел, спасибо c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой, немножко топорный, но рабочий вариант используя jq и стили BS. Хотя У бутстрапа есть чёткий гайд, как делать меню, но меня напрягают дублирующиеся меню и бургер справа (по мне, ему место слева), поэтому набросал свой костыль.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
   $(".navbar-collapse").toggleClass("active");
   $(".menu-toggle span").toggleClass("glyphicon-menu-hamburger glyphicon-remove")
  })
 })
```

```css
a.navbar-brand {
    display: none;
} 
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-collapse {
 display: none;
}
.navbar-collapse.active {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 left: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 /* padding-left: 15px; */
 width: 100%;
 height: calc(100% - 52px);
}
a.navbar-brand {
    display: block;
}
.navbar {
    position: static !important;
}
html {
   position:relative;
   height:100%;
}
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand menu-toggle" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
   </div>
       <div class="navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contacts</a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
  <div class="container">
   some content here
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за правки, скопировал неверно и не сразу разобрался, как править во встроенном редакторе